# AttributeError at /accounts/login/ 'User' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm new to django and trying to get user authentication working. I have setup a very basic login form and view but I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/login/ 'User' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I'm confused because I don't try and access User.user 
I know it has to be something in the first else statement because an authenticated user just redirects to "/" as it should 
Here is the view:

```
def login(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
  else:
    if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST['username']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
          login(user)
          return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
      return HttpResponse("There was an error logging you in")
    else:
      return render_to_response("registration/login.html", 
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The error is raised in views.py, line 15: if request.user.is_authenticated():

Comment: What line does it implicate? Also, have you deleted pyc files, and restarted the server?

Comment: Please add the part where the exception is raised

Comment: Sorry, I just added the error line. @Marcin - I just tried deleting pyc files and restarting the server but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view function is called `login`, and it takes a single parameter, `request`.

In line 11 of your view, you call `login(user)`. Now, you probably meant that to be the login function from `django.contrib.auth`, and presumably you have imported it from there at the top of the view. But Python can only have one thing using a name at once: so when you named your view `login`, it overwrote the existing reference to that name.

The upshot of this is that that line calls *your* view, not the login function. (That's why you're getting that particular error: the first line of your view checks `request.user`, taking `request` from the first parameter which usually is the request - but in your case, you've passed `user` as the first parameter, and of course user doesn't itself have a user param.)

The solution is to either rename your view to something else, or do `from django.contrib import auth` and call `auth.login(user)` inside your view.

Answer (score 1):

login must have 2 arguments, request and user. If the request isn't given login can't set cookies etc. So do:

```
login(request, user)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: TypeError at /accounts/login/
login() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Rename your view to for example login_view. Now your view is used for login